# WordPress Spacing Issue while submitting any Post

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme. I wrote a line and hit enter after that I put some initial white spaces to start the paragraph but when I publish the post the initial white spaces to the start of new paragraph not appears in that post. 
e.g.

This is my first post.

```
             This is my first first post.
```

After publishing in wordpress it shows:

This is my first post.

This is my first post.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

For inline spacing you can use `&nbsp;` inside the wordpress editor. Use it like `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` to space 3 times.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I did what you say but it shows me &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; as a text in post instead of spaces. Please suggest!

Comment: You probably used it on the Visual editor. Use it on the Text editor

Answer (score 0):

Don't use spaces to indent your paragraphs. Instead target your paragraphs with the CSS [text-indent](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-indent/) property in your theme's CSS. The indentation of a paragraph is *presentation*, and should be controlled by the CSS. The paragraphs themselves are content, and shouldn't have their presentation hardcoded into the HTML.

Separating the presentation into the CSS leaves you free to change/remove all the indentation at once any time later just by editing a single line of code, rather than having to edit every paragraph you've ever written.

```css
/* Use whatever selector will target your post's paragraphs in your theme's style.css */
p {
  text-indent: 24px;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras at elit nibh, in pretium tellus. Donec id dui mi. Nam malesuada, velit sed porta mollis, dolor felis eleifend diam.</p>
<p>Here's another one. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras at elit nibh, in pretium tellus. Donec id dui mi. Nam malesuada, velit sed porta mollis, dolor felis eleifend diam.</p>
```

Comment: Does text-indent get the spaces on runtime?

Comment: I guess this applies to all paragraphs. What if i put white-spaces on example alternate paragraphs or lines?

Comment: Then you could use a CSS selector that just targeted the alternate paragraphs, e.g. `p:nth-child(odd)` instead of plain `p`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As alternate is just an example. I want if user enter spaces to the start of paragraph then it should reflect on wordpress post.

Comment: Then you probably want to add `white-space: pre-wrap;` as a CSS property for your paragraphs. That should allow spaces to show up while not affecting the word-wrapping.